# How to load JSON data into JavaScript from separate php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am very new to JavaScript and php and am having trouble reading my JSON data into a JavaScript JSON object.

I have a JSON file (data.json) along with data.php:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('data.json');
echo $data;
?>
```

and this JavaScript:

```
function getdata() {
    var jsonData = null;
    jsonData = $.get("data.php");
    var json = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
}
```

This throws **JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier “object”** in the console at the line:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does data.json exist and does it contain valid JSON?

Answer (score 0):

$.get is async and does not return data

You can do this:

```
$.get("data.php",function(jsonData) { 
  var json = $.parseJSON(jsonData); 
  /* process the JSON here too */
});
```

or this - using [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

```
$.getJSON("data.php",function(jsonObject) { 
  /* process the JSON here */
});
```

Your server should return `application/json` in the last example